# What type of input check can be performed against binary data in C++?

Tags: c++, validation

let's say I have a function like this in C++, which I wish to publish to third parties. I want to make it so that the user will know what happened, should he/she feeds invalid data in and the library crashes.

Let's say that, if it helps, I can change the interface as well.

```
int doStuff(unsigned char *in_someData, int in_data_length);
```

Apart from application specific input validation (e.g. see if the binary begins with a known identifier etc.), what can be done? E.g. can I let the user know, if he/she passes in `in_someData` that has only 1 byte of data but passes in 512 as `in_data_length`?

Note: I already asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516272/is-it-not-possible-to-make-a-c-application-crash-proof), but let me ask from another angle..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It cannot be checked whether the parameter `in_data_length` passed to the function has the correct value. If this were possible, the parameter would be redundant and thus needless.

But a vector from the standard template library solves this:

```
int doStuff(const std::vector<unsigned char>& in_someData);
```

So, there is no possibility of a "NULL buffer" or an invalid data length parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you would know how many bytes passed by `in_someData` why would you need `in_data_length` at all?

Actually, you can only check `in_someData` for `NULL` and `in_data_length` for positive value. Then return some error code if needed. If a user passed some garbage to your function, this problem is obviously not yours.

Answer (score -2):

In C++, the magic word you're looking for is "exception".  That gives you a method to tell the caller something went wrong.  You'll end up with code something like

```
int 
doStuff(unsigned char * inSomeData, int inDataLength) throws Exception {
    // do a test
    if(inDataLength == 0)
       throw new Exception("Length can't be 0");
    // only gets here if it passed the test
    // do other good stuff
    return theResult;
}
```

Now, there's another problem with your specific example, because there's no universal way in C or C++ to tell how long an array of primitives really is.  It's all just bits, with `inSomeData` being the address of the first bits.  Strings are a special case, because there's a general convention that a zero byte ends a string, but you can't depend on that for binary data -- a zero byte is just a zero byte.

**Update**

This has currently picked up some downvotes, apparently by people misled by the comment that exception specifications had been deprecated.  As I noted in a comment below, this isn't actually true -- while the specification *will be* deprecated in C++11, it's still part of the language now, so unless questioner is a time traveler writing in 2014, the throws clause is still the correct way to write it in C++.

Also note that the original questioner says "I want to make it so that the user will know what happened, should he/she feeds [sic] invalid data in and the library crashes."  Thus the question is not just what can I do to validate the input data (answer: not much unless you know more about the inputs than was stated), but then how do I tell the caller they screwed up?  And the answer to that is "use the exception mechanism" which has certainly *not* been deprecated.

Comment: exception specifications (like in your example are depreciated)

Comment: That's not strictly true; exceptions *will be* deprecated in C++11, they're still part of the current standard: http://herbsutter.com/2010/03/13/trip-report-march-2010-iso-c-standards-meeting/